# HTML Canvas not drawing extreme points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

For some reason, HTML canvas isn't drawing a line between extreme points. Same goes with SVG. I am trying to run the following simple snippet:

As you see, the point with 10^9 draws fine but the one with 10^10 does not. Is there a particular reason? Am I missing something here? Or can I please be pointed to a reference link? I did search but couldn't find a relevant answer.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// draws
//ctx.moveTo(10, -1000000000);

// does not draw
ctx.moveTo(10, -10000000000);

ctx.lineTo(200, 100);

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Here's a fiddle if that helps: https://jsfiddle.net/qov72ag4/

Comment: Both work fine for me on FF. Why do you need to draw such a line starting from billions of pixels off canvas anyway?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I'm rendering a curve which has outliers and the above billion positioned point is one of them. I have the option to remove outliers but still was wondering why this doesn't work or was there something I was doing wrong.

Comment: And @ggorlen, by the way I just noticed that SVG doesn't render the same points (using path) on neither Chrome nor FF. Strange.

Comment: I played with it a bit, and the min value I can get it to draw is `-2147483583`, which in hex is `-7fffffbf`, which is suspiciously close to the minimum int32 value. I suspect it has something to do with an int32 conversion somewhere.

Comment: OK, never mind, because at 1e10, setting the `lineTo` y coordinate to at least 512 does draw the line.

Comment: For now, if a point is outside the domain for my curve and if that point is an outlier like the one I referred to, I draw the line up to a certain % of the domain (less than the billionth point) and that resolved it for now. I'll keep this task open just in case.

Comment: OK. I might suggest that if the slope of the line is above a certain huge threshold, just draw a vertical line and hard-cap the values. I also could not reproduce the issue on Firefox, FWIW, so I think this is a webkit-specific implementation detail, though I'd be curious to know what the differences are!

Comment: Cool. That's a good suggestion. Thank you. FF works good for this but still not for SVG. Probably the underlying implementation for extreme points. Do try the same in Safari when you get a chance. That is a different level :p